# Percentage from a dataframe

Tags: r

A very basic question, as I am new to R.
What I have is data like this in a dataframe:

```
     DESCRI   Region     area
1    Houses   1          1.225305e-04
2    Gardens  1          5.444932e-04
3    Forest   1          6.151541e-04
4    Lake     1          2.903044e-05
5    Sea      1          2.451042e-04
6    Houses   2          2.739274e-06
7    Gardens  2          1.223057e-04
8    Forest   2          3.869934e-04
9    Lake     2          3.945288e-06
10   Sea      2          1.884626e-06
```

I need something like this:

```
     Region 1: X% Houses
               Y% Gardens
               Z% Forest
               V% Lake
               Y% Sea

     Region 2: X% Houses
               Y% Gardens
               Z% Forest
               V% Lake
               Y% Sea
```

The data.table package can probably somehow do this, but I have not found the solution. All I manage to get is an added colums for percentage.

```
     DESCRI   Region     area           perc
1    Houses   1          1.225305e-04   0.03e-04
2    Gardens  1          5.444932e-04   0.02e-04
```

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[,ArSum:= sum(area) , Region][,100*(area/ArSum) ,.(DESCRI,Region)]`

Comment: It works, but it does not summarize the percentages of land classes for each of the regions. I keep getting the percentages in a separate column as shown above.

Comment: That is a formatting issue.  You can use `paste` for that.  From the expected output showed, it seems to be a single string.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I tried to use paste, but can't get it to work.

Comment: Please do tell us whether the expected output is two columns or a single string.

Comment: It does not really matter, but single string is probably better.

Comment: Try  `str1 <- setDT(df1)[,ArSum:= sum(area) , Region][, as.character(round(100*(area/ArSum),2)) ,.(DESCRI,Region)][, paste(sprintf('%s%% %s',   V1, DESCRI),collapse='\n'), Region][, paste0('Region ', Region,':', V1)];
 cat(paste(str1, collapse='\n\n\n'),'\n')`

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: "Unexpected symbol" error when I try to create object str1. Could it be the "%s%% %s"? I checked the input, ArSum and V1 are there, so it must be something minor that is producing the error.

Comment: I didn't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
 str1 <- setDT(df1)[,ArSum:= sum(area) , by = Region
     ][, as.character(round(100*(area/ArSum),2)), by = .(DESCRI,Region)
      ][, paste(sprintf('%s%% %s', V1, DESCRI),collapse='\n'), by = Region
        ][, paste0('Region ', Region,':', V1)]
 cat(paste(str1, collapse='\n\n\n'),'\n')
# Region 1:7.87% Houses
#34.99% Gardens
#39.53% Forest
#1.87% Lake
#15.75% Sea


#Region 2:0.53% Houses
#23.62% Gardens
#74.73% Forest
#0.76% Lake
#0.36% Sea
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to R, it might be worth walking through how to do this in a totally transparent way, using a for-loop.  Here's one possibility:

```
n <- length(unique(my.data.frame$Region)) # n is how many regions you have.

all.percents <- vector()  
for(i in 1:n){  # For every region
  percent <- vector()
  new.data.frame <- my.data.frame[my.data.frame$Region==i, ]  #Make a dataframe with just that region
  for(j in 1:dim(new.data.frame)[1]){
    percent[j] <- new.data.frame$area[j]/sum(new.data.frame$area) # and calculate the percent for each land cover type.
  }
  all.percents <- c(all.percents, percent)  # combine the vectors of percents for all of the different regions
}

my.data.frame$percent <- all.percents # put the vector of percents back into your dataframe.
```

Note, for this to work you need to first sort your original dataframe so that the regions are all in ascending order.  The order of the land cover classes within regions will not matter, and can even be inconsistent between regions.

Comment: Thanks. The regions are in ascending order now, but I get the error "invalid (NULL) left side of assignment" when running    41 <- length(unique(PercentData$Region)) # n is how many regions you have.

Comment: Ah, got it. The n was not just a placeholder. The loop works now, but I get "Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  RHS of assignment to new column 'percent' is zero length but not empty list(). For new columns the RHS must either be empty list() to create an empty list column, or, have length > 0; e.g. NA_integer_, 0L, etc." when I try to put the vector back into the dataframe

Comment: Sorry--there was a minor typo above, which has now been corrected.  Whereas I meant to write `dim(new.data.frame)[1]`, I had previously written `dim(new.data.frame)[2]`.  Hope it works now.

Comment: There is something wrong with my dataframe now. I get the error "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "percent", value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : Replacemnet has 42 rows, data has 200". I have 42 regions, but 200 land cover classes in total.